# Determining dob from age when importing offline patients medical records

Tags: mysql, csv, import, probability, etl

My situation is strange, because I need to determine the approximate dob of patients from their age & registered_date. I'm currently importing large number of patient records from several offline sources and found the age was hard-coded.

Now I'm confused whether I should store the hard-coded age or compute the dob from registered_date and age mentioned at the time of registered_date, considering their registered_date as their dob. This way, I don't need to update the age every year? Please guide me to find most suitable approach to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the date of birth, rather than the age. Compute the date of birth as:

`dob = date of registration - (age at registration * 365) - (365/2)`,

assuming you have the `date of registration` and `age at registration` (in years) in the patient records.

I am subtracting the `365/2` because without it the formula would assume everyone registered on their birthday, and so would say they are the youngest they could possibly be given the data. In reality people register on average half way between birthdays, so would on average be 6 months older than that.